# Two consecutive prepositions--- in below

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

> Students studying **in {below** 6th grade} are not allowed to go on this trip.

Here **in** and **below** both are working as a preposition.

Is the sentence natural?

What are the other ways to say this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can either say:

> Students studying in 5th grade or below are not allowed to go on this
>   trip.

or

> Students studying below 6th grade are not allowed to go on this trip.

In the first case, **below** acts as an adverb modifying **5th**. In the second case, **below** acts as preposition, and *in* is not needed in the phrase.